# Difference between time_steps and features in a LSTM input of Keras. Can anyone explain with an example?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a LSTM model to train sequences using Keras. I have gone through some posts here but unable to find a narration that explains what does samples, features and time steps mean in the context of RNNs or LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

Samples. One sequence is one sample. A batch is comprised of one or more samples.

Time Steps. One time step is one point of observation in the sample.

Features. One feature is one observation at a time step.

Comment: let me explain with example:
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]] 
this array considered as 1 sequence(sample)
in this sequence there is five time steps [1,2] , [2,3] , [3,4] , [4,5] , [5,6] 
in each sample there is two feature

Comment: check this link
https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/